# Minimal Bazel BUILD and WORKSPACE files for compiling "monster" example including sample_text.cpp

Tags: bazel, flatbuffers, bazel-rules

I'm new to both FlatBuffers and Bazel.  Can anyone post a minimal example for compiling flatc itself, the monster_generated.h file, and then sample_text.cpp?

When I run:

- bazel build flatbuffers:flatc

I get the following error:

- Unable to find package for @rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl: The repository '@rules_cc' could not be resolved.

I then build flatc with CMake temporarily, and moved on to building sample_text.cpp with Bazel.  I thought I found a minimal example here:

- https://github.com/hazelnusse/flatbuffers-bazel

However, when I run:

- bazel build flatbuffers-bazel:sample_binary

I get:

- fatal error: 'monster_generated.h' file not found

When I cheat and bring a copy of monster_generated.h (manually made with flatc, itself compiled with CMake) into the workspace, and add it to the srcs section of BUILD, I then get:

- every rule of type cc_flatbuffers_compile implicitly depends upon the target '@flatbuffers//:flatc', but this target could not be found because of: no such package '@flatbuffers//': The repository '@flatbuffers' could not be resolved

This is probably a basic issue since it does appear that Bazel is supported, so any advice is very welcome!

Thanks,

Sean

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `rules_cc` into your WORKSPACE in order to have it locally.

```
    http_archive(
        name = "rules_cc",
        urls = ["https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/archive/262ebec3c2296296526740db4aefce68c80de7fa.tar.gz"],
        strip_prefix = "rules_cc-262ebec3c2296296526740db4aefce68c80de7fa",
        sha256 = "3057c13fa4d431eb0e7a9c28eea13f25987d29f869406b5ee3f2bd9c4134cb0c",
    )
```